# how to invoke the add_custom_command

Tags: cmake

I want to use `add_custom_command` to generate a file. I know I can use `add_custom_target` to set the DEPENDS to invoke the command. But this will also create a target(like in visual studio, it will create a .vcxproj). I use another `add_custom_command`, and then set the DEPENDS but it does not work. Why?  Which level dependency can invoke it?

Are there any methods to invoke the `add_custom_command` like `make install` invokes the  `install` command .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_custom_command()` function corresponds to Makefile's rule. It list commands which are needed to produce some file. If you wish to be able to run in from `make` invocation, you should wrap it into `add_custom_target(tgt DEPENDS cmd), just as you said.

So, there is no way to execute custom_command's without creating custom_target's for them.

Comment: Thank you very much,  so add_customer_target is the only way to execute it . but you now there are some other commands that can set dependency. so why these command can't invoke it.

Comment: Because these command aren't executed themselves. If you `add_custom_command(OUTPUT a)` and then `add_custom_command(OUTPUT b DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/a)`, these command wouldn't be executed during `make`. But when you do `add_custom_target(tgt DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/b)`, you can now issue `make tgt` and this will run both commands.